# Conversion to formula in R: Predict Y (factor variable) with X (data frame)

Tags: r

I am working on a classification problem where for my training data I have a data frame `X` and a factor variable `Y`, and I would like predict my variable `Y` from `X`.

The function `cforest` from the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package has the following interface

```
 cforest(formula, data = list(), ...)
```

Where:

> **formula**: a symbolic description of the model to be fit. Note that
>             symbols like ':' and '-' will not work and the tree will make
>             use of all variables listed on the rhs of 'formula'.
>
> **data**: a data frame containing the variables in the model.

However, when I try:

```
# Build a random set of training vectors X
X <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(2000)))

# Build Y from X
Y <- runif(1)*X[,1]*X[,2]^2+runif(1)*X[,3]/X[,4]

cforest(Y, data = X, ...)
```

I get an error:

```
..
10: ParseFormula(formula, data = data)
...
5: cforest(Y, data = X, ...) at ..
```

From the traceback it looks like I am not using the interface to `cforest` correctly. I have read about R formulas (`?formula` and  [this tutorial](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html), which was very helpful), and I understand the concept abstractly, but I don't know how to convert my prediction problem (which I would write `Y ~ X`) to the formula syntax.

How can I convert my call to `cforest` using a formula?

Comment: R formulas usually take the form `outcome ~ variables`, where you can think of the tilde `~` as meaning something like "described by".

Comment: Please make this question reproducible. Is `Y` a column in your data.frame `X`? Have you looked at `?formula` for what a formula is?

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put in to making the example reproducible and adding extra info, but in this case you're probably better off carefully going through the examples at the bottom of the `?cforest` help page (I'm not the source of the downvote, btw)

Comment: Thanks @Marius. The examples in the `cforest` documentation (actually, the `party` package) load data in a format that seems to be directly amenable to R formulas. I think I need to put X and Y in a dataframe and then represent my prediction problem symbolically in the formula. Anyways, I will keep investigating. Thanks.

Comment: @Marius. In case you are interested I finally found the answer (which I posted below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the following syntax:

```
cf.model = cforest(Y ~ ., data=X, ...)
```

which basically says "use all variables in the dataframe `X` when trying to predict `Y`"